# Shouldn't duplicate questions be closed for down-votes?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Why are down votes open for questions marked [duplicate]?

I see lot of questions marked duplicate being down-voted without any specific comments. The number of down-votes keep increasing with no update in the actual Q & A or comments put up.

I think the **down-votes also must be closed** within a period so as to discourage unnecessary down-votes.

Comment: If a question is an obvious duplicate, this shows lack of effort from the OP. Thus lack of effort leads to DVs.

Comment: @TheLostMind I am in complete agreement with that, but once a question is marked duplicate it doesn't need down-votes any more. The "duplicate" or "closed" tag itself shows it.

Comment: Well, if you are allowed to up-vote it, then you can DV it as well. Unless it gets deleted

Comment: Why not downvote a question that was not either researched or that the OP knew was a duplicate when posting it.?  Can't be bothered to Google, post anyway to get someone else to search?  Sounds like a necessary downvote to me, already marked as dup or not.

Comment: @TheLostMind Don't allow Upvotes/Downvotes on it. Lock it.

Comment: Posts should be locked only when something bad is going on.

Comment: @MartinJames How does the down voter know what the OP was intending to ask? Maybe the OP later realized that it was a duplicate and wants to just close it, so his question just keeps getting down-voted why?

Comment: @TheLostMind I meant lock the voting.

Comment: @AniMenon  'Maybe he later realized' too late!   The idea is that posters should search FIRST, then post.   If it was up to me, any question where Googling the exact title gives an exact SO answer as the first/second result should get an immediate -100 downvote for wasting everyone else's time, but that's just me.

Comment: @MartinJames I am not talking about obvious questions.

Comment: I'm now downvoting this now because I did read it, and don't like the suggestion that I would downvote without reading.   You understand how insulting it is to imply that downvoters can not, or do not, read questions?

Comment: ..as for comments, the 'comments on downvotes' issue has been gone over on meta again, and again, and again.  It's a huge muliple-duplicate, and anyone suggesting it now has not done any research and deserves downvotes.

Comment: @MartinJames Thats upto you. It was directed to the flood of around 10 down-votes which the question received. (-12 and only 2 users commented)

Comment: @MartinJames All duplicates about comments suggest one thing that is : *to put a comment* when down-voted so that the OP knows why his question received it!

Comment: @MartinJames It is in no way a duplicate to that. And my question is about **closing/locking votes to duplicate questions** not commenting on duplicate question!

Comment: @AniMenon maybe you have a point, since this question received an extra three downvotes since I proposed it as a dup.

Comment: ' my question is about closing/locking votes to duplicate questions not commenting on duplicate question' ....... 'Down-voters please read the question and comment/answer.'

Comment: @MartinJames  'Down-voters please read the question and comment/answer.' was to promote a discussion on this.

Comment: Just asserting it isn't a duplicate is pointless; if you think that, explain how the existing answers fail to address your point.

Comment: To me not all duplicates are bad. I only downvote bad ones.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865125/how-to-handle-multiple-postfix-and-prefix-operators-in-a-single-statement-in-gcc   tell me that does not deserve 100 downvotes..

Comment: *Don't allow Upvotes/Downvotes on it. Lock it.* But that prevents someone from getting any up votes after improving their post. It's not fair to prevent those that do the work of fixing their posts from getting up votes (or block good dupes from getting up votes).

Comment: @BSMP Once an edit is made the question is reopened and then the Up-votes/Down-votes should be made usable as usual.

Comment: @AH Thats good, but not all follow that.

Comment: *Once an edit is made the question is reopened* No, it isn't. People have to cast re-open votes in a question's favor before a question is re-opened. This also doesn't address not allowing up votes for a duplicate that's considered a good signpost.

Comment: @BMSP exactly allow all up/down votes when required, but once a post is tagged duplicate/closed its mostly unnecessary.

Comment: But there are exception like the one @MartinJames put up. Its deleted but maybe it deserved down-votes.

Answer (score 12):

I get your point.

If something is closed as a duplicate, the job is done - the dupe is now a signpost pointing to a (hopefully) useful original question, and everyone should just walk away. No need to pile on, right?

That, however, isn't the whole story.

Duplicate questions generally get heavily downvoted when they would have been *really, really* trivial to Google.

If that's the case, the duplicate doesn't add any value to the world: it doesn't provide a new combination of keywords, of ways to pose a question, that makes the Q&A better discoverable on the Internet.

At worst, the new duplicate is actively *harmful* by clogging a Google results page with yet another useless duplicate that is almost identical to a thousand others (many Google searches for trivial programming tasks will show what  I mean - dozens and dozens of almost-identical SO Q&A of varying quality.)

In that case, the role of downvotes as a filter becomes more important: they might lead to the duplicate getting removed, and ultimately (if you ask a *lot* of bad questions) to consequences for the user.